# Is there a way to give a "nickname" to a variable with a long name/path without assignment in C

Tags: c

In case where I use data that is stored "deep" inside structures I want a way to use a shorter name to refer to it to increase readability. Is there a way to do it without an assignment to a local variable or pointer (which aren't needed functionally).

Example:

```
int foo (struct1 *in_strct1, struct2 *in_strct2, struct3 *out_strct3)
// an exaggerated example for a function that calculates one of the zeroes of
// a quadratic equation, where the inputs and the output are hidden very deep
// inside the structures. 
{
    /*unnecessary assignment that aren't needed functionally, but without *
     *them the code would be unreadable.                                  */
    double a = in_strct1->sublevel1.sublevel2.somearray[5].a;  
    double b = in_strct2->somearray[3].sublevel2.sublevel3.b;
    double c = in_strct2->someotherarray[6].inside.even_deeper_inside.almost_there.c;
    double *res = &out_strct3->a_very_long_corredor.behind_the_blue_door.under_the_table.inside_the_box.on_the_left.res;
    //actual logic
    *res = (-b+sqrt(pow(b,2)-4*a*c))/(2*a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A `#define` macro? Or implement getter/setter..

Comment: A `#define` is not restricted to the local scope, and is risky, because if you forget to `#undef` it will continue to affect rest of the code, Is there a better (safer) solution?

Comment: Your current use of local variables is probably the best you can do. If you somehow  are worried about unnecessary assignment - don't worry about that, there's no performance penalty when you tell your compiler to optimize your code.

Comment: Yes it will. But if you introduce a good convention.. For instance prefixing the macro with a function name.

Comment: If all the data is at the same level in the structure, it's common to set up a shortcut pointer: `struct whatever *sp = &in_strct2->somearray[3].sublevel2.sublevel3; res = sp->a + sp->b + sp->c`.  But that doesn't help in your case.

Comment: A macro can be `#undef`ed after the function.

Comment: This situation is very common in linux device drivers. Those drivers are written almost exactly this way.

Comment: What is your **actual** problem with the code shown? Why do you not want to use explicit temporary variables? You always should code for readability. Do not try premature optimisations.

Comment: @olaf, because it adds unnecesery assignmets, which cost memory and time.

Comment: And this duscussion does not cost time? Did you benchmark? Do you have any proof the code is less performant? What Assembler code is generated? is it really different? Do you have the slightest proof for your claims?

Comment: @IlyaMelamed No it does not. A compiler will optimize this away.

Comment: Sometimes when I see issues about style/efficiency, issues about functionality seem to be ignored: The equation look more like one to solve "one of the zeros of a quadratic equation" than "one of the poles of a quadratic equation".

Comment: @chux, you are correct, i fixed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You should always strive for readability, and your defining `a`, `b`, and `c` helps to attain that.

I wouldn't worry about any perceived overhead in doing that: a good compiler ought to optimise out `a`, `b`, and `c`. Check the output assembly if you have any doubts.

Writing `const double a` in place of `double a` etc. will help the compiler even more.

Comment: While this is true, I'm not sure how it answers the question.

Comment: Does so now, imho at least.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer actually if we define 'without an assignment' as 'no assignment in the compiled program' this does.

Comment: I'd recommend emphasize adding the `const` a bit more, because this will also add some robustness in terms of possible future modifications

Comment: Hmmm, IMO adding `const to `const struct1 *in_strct1`, especially for its function declaration, is even more useful as the `const` in `const double a` can be deduced from the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

As Eugene points out in his comment, a #define could be used, though it does have scoping risks.  An alternative is to create a pointer to it.  The pointer is, effectively, an alias to the location.

Unfortunately, this does require an assignment... But short of an assignment I do not believe this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Using pointers to do this might make it impossible in some situations for some compilers to optimise them out, thus making performance worse than using normal variables.  However for this specific example pointers would probably be optimisable in all cases I can think of.

In your case I recommend using local #defines within the function body and then #undef them again before the end of the function.

Something like...

```
int foo (struct1 *in_strct1, struct2 *in_strct2, struct3 *out_strct3)
{
#define a (in_strct1->sublevel1.sublevel2.somearray[5].a)
#define b (in_strct2->somearray[3].sublevel2.sublevel3.b)
#define c (in_strct2->someotherarray[6].inside.even_deeper_inside.almost_there.c)

#define res (out_strct3->a_very_long_corredor.behind_the_blue_door.under_the_table.inside_the_box.on_the_left.res)
    //actual logic
    res = (-b+sqrt(pow(b,2)-4*a*c))/(2*a);
    return 0;

#undef a
#undef b
#undef c
}
```